# Android broadcast receivers and passing intents

Tags: java, android, networking

I have a simple broadcast receiver set to receive system intents informing my application of a change in network status. The idea is to either show a dialog telling the user they have left the WiFI network on which the app runs or have lost their connection altogether.

```
public class NetworkChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)){

        boolean connected = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED,false);
        if(!connected){
            //connection off
            Log.w("Network Changed","SUPPLICATION_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION");



        }
    }else if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)){

        NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if(info.isConnected()){
            //connection on or WIFI changed
            Log.w("Network Changed","NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is it possible for me to even display a dialog in this manner? I have no way of knowing where the user is in the application, an unknown state for when the broadcast is received. My other option is to jump the user back to my Login activity using an intent with a string and boolean extra to test. Is it bad programming practice to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I have no way of knowing where the user is in the application,
```

In that case when you receive the Broadcast You should consider showing notification in notification bar

> My other option is to jump the user back to my Login activity using an
>   intent with a string and boolean extra to test. Is it bad

When User will click on notification you can navigate them to Login Activity.

Answer (score 0):

place the same brodcast receiver in your each activity in this case which activity will be in front will receive this broadcast and then you can show a dialog saying connection is lost in that activity and do whatever you want.

Comment: Sounds like a cool idea. Do you know what will happen if the app isn't visible on the screen? I know the network changed intent will still be broadcast but will my app still receive it?

Comment: if you will just put the receivers in your activities and at the time of broadcast if there is no activity of your app is in front (app is not visible) then your app will not able to catch that broadcast and also doesn't produce any error.. so if you also want to receive that broadcast when your app isn't visible then you should also use that separate broadcast receiver which will also declared in manifest.

Comment: please consider accepting answer by clicking on tick below vote count if it really helped